# Did Dumbledore already know this?

Tags: plot-explanation, harry-potter, the-deathly-hallows-2

Did Dumbledore know that Harry Potter would die or not? What happened to the stone which was gift of death?

Comment: Why did harry throw that stone which is gifted by death

Answer (score 5):

> Did Dumbledore know that Harry Potter would die or not?

Dumbledore already knew that Harry would die. And it was necessary to kill Voldemort.

When Harry looks into Snape's memory, we can see Dumbledore and Snape having a conversation at Astronomy Tower.

> **Snape:** So when the time comes, the boy will die.
>
> **Dumbledore:** Yes. He will die. And Voldemort should do this.

We can see here that Dumbledore knew that Harry will die.

> What happened to the stone which was gift of death?

It is called *The Resurrection Stone*. Harry used this to call his parents, Sirius, and Lupin.

Last time we saw, this stone was dropped by Harry on the ground in the forest.

Comment: If he could revive anyone then why he hadn't revived all of his family

Comment: One more thing according to Voldemort he had to make 7 horcrux and according to the Dumbledore Harry was the horcrux which was not known to the Lord Voldemort then Harry had destroyed six horcrux what about the 7th

Comment: Because Harry was the 8 horcrux as voldmort didn't know about harry

Comment: Harry already heard the story of Three Brothers in HP 7.2 and there is no use of reviving his family. Harry was also one of his Horcruxes and when the part of Voldemort inside him was needed to be killed in order to kill Voldemort. There were only 7 horcruxes only, not 8.

Comment: @supersaiyan Actually, Tom says to Prof. Slughorn he'd like to split his soul into 7 parts. That means that he wanted 6 objects to contain part of his soul, such that there are 7 total soul parts. To split your soul into seven parts, you need six Horcruxes. Harry is the seventh (pseudo) Horcrux that Voldemort didn't know about, and didn't intend to exist. More info on the Horcruxes [here](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Horcrux#List_of_Voldemort.27s_Horcruxes)

Answer (score 0):

Dumbledore actually knows that Harry would not die. There is a bit towards the end part when Harry tells him Voldemort took blood from his body. Dumbledore then realizes that the protection that Lily provided also now runs in Voldemort's body. There by he makes a good 'guess' that Harry wouldnt die - as he tells Harry during the dream/imaginary conversation he has with him at what seems like "King's Cross Station".. Again covered well in the book.. not so much in the movies